# pic16f877A timer not working

Tags: pic

i wrote a code in mikroc for pic16f877A in which i have used a timer0 and timer1. i debug my code and found that timer0 is not working but i am not able to understand the reason behind it. I even checked datasheet for the OPTION_REG but couldn't figure out the problem plz help. i am new to pic programming. I just uploaded the function in which timer0 and timer1 is setup. UART is used to check whether each line is getting executed and i found after printing the value of TMR1H it stops.

```
 int feedback()
 {
 sh = 0;                                 //variable to come out of the while loop after interrupt occured.
 UART1_WRITE_TEXT("inside feedback");
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 TMR0=193;
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR0);
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 INTCON=0xA0;
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(INTCON);
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 TMR1L=0;
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR1L);
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 TMR1H=0;
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR1H);
 UART1_Write(13); // newline
                                               //here the problem starts
 OPTION_REG.PSA=0;
 OPTION_REG.PS2=0;
 OPTION_REG.PS1=1;
 OPTION_REG.PS0=0;
 OPTION_REG.T0SE=0;
 OPTION_REG.T0CS=0;
 UART1_WRITE_TEXT("timer0 start");     //this msg and following all messages does not show up 
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 T1CON=0x07;
 UART1_WRITE_TEXT("timer1 start");
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

 sh=1;
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(sh);
 UART1_Write(13); // newline

while(sh==1){
Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(sh);
UART1_Write(13); // newline

UART1_WRITE_TEXT("inside while loop");
}

UART1_WRITE_TEXT("outside while loop");

TMR1H=TMR1H*1000;
sh=TMR1H+TMR1L;
actualOut=(60*2*sh)/8;
Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(actualOut);
UART1_Write(13); // newline

return actualOut;
}
void interrupt(){

 T1CON=0x00;
 sh=0;

}

///////////main function/////////////

 void main() {

 UART1_Init(9600);

 pro=0.5,i=0,der=0;
 setPoint=80,sel=1;
 actualOut=20;
 pOut=0,iOut=0,dOut=0;
 out=16;
 error=0,lastError=0;

 ADCON0=0;
 ADCON1=0x0f;
 CMCON = 0x07;
 PORTC=0;
 TRISC = 0b00000001;

  while(1){

 out = pid(actualOut);

 duty=(short)out;
 pwm(duty);

 actualOut = feedback();

  }
  }
```

Comment: Post your config bit settings too. Have you remembered to disable the Watchdog Timer?

Comment: You can't just slap together a few calls to some canned libraries and expect everything to work without you having to actually *understand* things.  For example, does UART1_WRITE just write a byte, or does it first wait for the UART to be ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to spend much time looking at higher level code with some compiler getting between me and the system.  However, you're not ever clearing the timer 1 interrupt condition.

Comment: i cleared interrupt and it worked thanku u @Olin Lathrop